# Koala GraphAPI does not fetch everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

So far I have read most of the tutorials about querying Facebook Graph with Koala and they helped me a lot. Though, I am not fully satisfied with results Koala provides. From what I've seen, there is a lack of shared statuses/links/images when fetching user's public stream:

```
@graph.get_connections("username", "feed", { :since => @date, :limit => 1000})
```

and a lack of posts by others when fetching fanpage's stream:

```
@graph.get_connections("fanpagename", "feed", { :since => @date, :limit => 1000}).
```

Is there any way around here ? What should I give to get_connections function to get as many results as possible (this is my main benchmark) ? So far I've tried with posts, feed and statuses - and feed gives the best results in my opinion.